# Searching in two fields using Bootstrap Typeahead in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, angular-ui-typeahead

I have two fields in my JSON: `first_name` and `last_name`.

I want to use Bootstrap typeahead.js, using Angular-UI.

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTemplate.html">
  <a>
    <span bind-html-unsafe="match.label | typeaheadHighlight:query"></span>
  </a>
</script>
  <input type="text" ng-model="result" typeahead="patient as patient.first_name for patient in ngGridUsersData.patients | filter:{first_name:$viewValue}" typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html">
```

What would I add in the `typeahead` field to search also in last_name?
What would I add in the template to display both the first and last name upon selection?

If the angular-ui directive doesnt have this functionality, then I guess I'll just concatenate the first and last name into one string.

**UPDATE:** 9/15/14
 Any idea how to display the first and last name in the search results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using a custom function for the typeahead, instead of using the filter:

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-model="result" 
       typeahead="patient as patient.first_name for patient in filterByName(ngGridUsersData.patients, $viewValue)" 
       typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html">

// ...snip...

function filterByName(patients, typedValue) {
    return patients.filter(function(patient) {
        matches_first_name = patient.first_name.indexOf(typedValue) != -1;
        matches_last_name = patient.last_name.indexOf(typedValue) != -1;

        return matches_first_name || matches_last_name;
    });
}
$scope.filterByName = filterByName;
```

Caveat: I haven't tested this code/yanked it from a project of mine, so there might be one or two errors that require some tweaking to fix.

Comment: Thanks, this has been useful to me. I did have to add var in front of  matches_first_name and  matches_last_name. Otherwise, it shows as undefined in the console.

Answer (score 3):

To display both the first name and last name in the search results amend michael0x2a's input markup to read:

```
 <input type="text" 
       ng-model="result" 
       typeahead="patient as patient.first_name + ' ' + patient.last_name for patient in filterByName(ngGridUsersData.patients, $viewValue)" 
       typeahead-template-url="customTemplate.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

**AngularJS UI Bootstrap – Typeahead – Filtering by multiple properties :**

The “uib-typeahead” attribute is where you put what fields you would like to filter by.

```
uib-typeahead="patient as (patient.first_name + ' ' + patient.last_name) for patient in $ctrl.patients | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
```